# How to upload a file to amazon S3 without passing it by a server?

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for a front-end solution for uploading files to amazon s3 (that is, not passing them through my server.

The solution I have found is
https://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

It might do the job, but it requier flash and this is the first sentence of the project description is:

SWFUpload has not been under active development for several years.

Here are my desired features, though none of them are nessesary

- No plugins
- Built with Amazon S3 in mind, handling buckets authentification etc.
- Some way to see file upload-progress
- Support from IE8+

Comment: An upload library I maintain, [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com) handles uploads directly to S3 in all browsers, including IE7.  It also supports chunking, auto-resume, retry, and a bunch of other features.  A live demo of the upload-to-s3 function can be found on the page I just linked to.

Answer (score 5):

kgu87 is correct, [this article](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) pretty much explains the entire process to upload files directly to S3 without passing them trough your own server.

You can also check out the AWS docs related to this on:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

If you're looking for an upload tool that supports HTML5 uploads directly to S3, check out [Plupload](http://plupload.com/)

They have a great article that explains how to set it up:

https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/wiki/Upload-to-Amazon-S3

The documentation describes a PHP service that's used to generate a policy and signature (both are required for S3 to accept your download) but you can use any language to generate those. Also, in certain use cases, you can just generate a one-time policy with a very high expiration time and hard code it into your upload form.

Answer (score 2):

You could start by using this tutorial as a baseline  , if you are asking about uploading from your web app -

http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434

Answer (score 0):

You could use this tool: http://aws.amazon.com/customerapps/Amazon-S3/Consumers/2069 free, and works in most browsers; doesn't require a server.

> > S3 Browser is a free client interface for users of the Amazon S3 service.
> >
> > It provides an easy to use GUI to manage your storage buckets and allows you to:
> >     - Browse, create, delete Amazon S3 buckets
> >     - Upload and download files to and from Amazon S3
> >     - Create public URLs to share the files.
> >     - Keep your files backed up on a multiple data centers.
> >     - Set Access Control on buckets and files.
> >
> > S3 Browser is free for non-commercial use.

Comment: This is not a browser-based solution. It's a Microsoft Windows software.